# Permutation and cycles decomposition

Tags: permutations, cyclic-decomposition

For the permutation cycle $\sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 4 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$, they decomposed it into $(3 4)(13)(45)(25)$. I don't see how this works because isn't the two-line notatoin basically saying
$1 \mapsto 4\mapsto 5\mapsto 2\mapsto 3\mapsto 1$ and the decomposition looks like it says: $3 \mapsto 4 \mapsto 1 \mapsto 3 \mapsto 4 \mapsto 5 \mapsto 2 \mapsto 5...$
Can anyone explain?

Comment: That decomposition must be read from right to left, not from left to right.

Comment: So it'd be $5 \mapsto 2$ but I'm not sure how to continue from the 2nd last bracket to the first. $5 \mapsto 4$...$3 \mapsto 1$...$4\mapsto 3$? There seems to be two 5's there

Answer (score 1):

In the decomposition as a product of transpositions, the product corresponds to `composition` of bijections, *starting from the right*. Thus, for instance:
$$2\mapsto 5\mapsto 4\mapsto 4\mapsto 3, \enspace\text{so that}\enspace 2\mapsto 3. $$

Comment: Wouldn't $3 \mapsto 1$ as well so $2 \mapsto 1$ instead?

Comment: Yes, $3\mapsto1$, but should it imply $2\mapsto 1$?

Comment: @Analysis122
You start from the right and move left, you don't go back to right.
They're like layers in an onion, you keep on move inwards (to the left)

Comment: @Bernard But if $2\mapsto 3$ and $3\mapsto 1$ then shouldn't $2 \mapsto  1$?

Comment: @Malcolm Hmm, I'm not quite understanding it.  I saw a cycle as $(1 2)(2 3)$ which I interpreted as $1 \mapsto 2, 2\mapsto 3$ so $1\mapsto 2\mapsto 3$. I'm interpreting your advice as $3\mapsto 2 \mapsto 1$? If so, I don't see how Bernard got his/her path then

Comment: I'm interpreting exactly the same way as @Malcolm. Taking the case of $1$, we have (from right to left): $\;1\mapsto 1\mapsto 1\mapsto 3\mapsto 4$, so $1\mapsto 4$.

Comment: @Bernard How come there 3 $ 1's$? Are you using the composition $(34)(13)(45)(23)$?

Comment: Yes, from the very beginning.